# How do you "undo" a local commit to the wrong branch

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I did some code changes in Visual Studio from the main branch and tried to commit the changes in a new branch in TortoiseHG, but apparently I accidentally committed the corrections to the main branch. I have not pushed the changes to the remote repository but if I try to do a "Backout" on the change I get the error message "Cannot backout change on a different branch", even though it clearly states that the changes have been committed to the main branch.

Does anyone know why I get this error message and how I can move the changes into the correct branch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove some commits in Mercurial that were applied to the wrong branch and then replay them on the correct one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317257/how-can-i-remove-some-commits-in-mercurial-that-were-applied-to-the-wrong-branch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by making a backup of all files in the commit, adding the extensions "eol" and "mq" in TortoiseHG, right-clicking on the draft branch and selecting "Modify History -> Strip...". Afterwards I simply added the backed up files again and committed them to the correct branch.

Since I'm new to using TortoiseHG I must advise others to be cautious about doing this.

Answer (score 4):

As long as your changes are not yet pushed anywhere else there are two options.

a) Use `hg rebase` to move one changeset and all of its descendents on top of another changeset:

```
 hg rebase -s FIRST_CHANGESET_TO_MOVE -d DESTINATION
```

b) The less recommended way, which only works if you want to undo ONE commit and haven't pulled or committed anything since, is to use `hg rollback`. But even in those cases `hg rebase` seems like the easier thing to use.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you don't want to Backout as that is for undoing pushed / published changes.

There are multiple ways to do this fix this:

Repository -> **Rollback**/Undo

This will undo you last commit and leave your working directly with the uncommitted changed. You can then recommit making sure to select the new branch name.

If for some reason Rollback/Undo doesn't work:

1. Update to the parent of the commit.
2. Right click on the commit -> **Revert all Files**
3. Commit the changes again - making sure to select the new branch name.
4. Right click on the previous commit you want to remove -> Modify History -> Strip (The strip extension will need to be enabled in File -> Settings -> Extensions)

Comment: I have done a couple of pulls after committing to the wrong branch, is that why the confirmation message says "Rollback to revision xxxx (undo pull)"? Can I keep undoing until the text says something like "Rollback to revision xxxx (undo commit)"? I also want to be absolutely sure that I'm only updating my local working directory, is that the case here?

Comment: Yes && No - multiple rollbacks never work for me && Look at the Phase column - if it doesn't say public then the commit Is prolly safe to modify.

Comment: Revert All Files is great - in this case you are 'reverting' to a newer version than you have updated to. Note that this must be done for each change otherwise you risk bunching all your changes together into one big change.